# Insert data to sqlite database from json parsing

Tags: android

I want to insert data to sqLite database in Android data parsing form json array data.

My code is as follow:

1) DBHelperClass - database creation

```
public class DueAmountDataBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public DueAmountDataBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, "abc.db", null, 1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String CREATE_TABLE_PRODUCT_DUE_AMT =
                "create table due_amt_tab(" +
                        "shopId text primary key, " +
                        "shopName text NOT NULL, " +
                        "teluguName text NOT NULL, " +
                        "place text NOT NULL, " +
                        "dueAmount text NOT NULL " +
                        ")";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_PRODUCT_DUE_AMT);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }

    public List<DueAmtDBModel> getShopdata() {
        List<DueAmtDBModel> data = new ArrayList<>();
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select * from due_amt_tab", null);
        StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
        DueAmtDBModel dataModel = null;
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            dataModel = new DueAmtDBModel();
            String shopId, shopName, teluguName, place, dueAmount;

            shopId = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("shopId"));
            shopName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("shopName"));
            teluguName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("teluguName"));
            place = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("place"));
            dueAmount = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("dueAmount"));

            dataModel.setShopId(shopId);
            dataModel.setShopName(shopName);
            dataModel.setTeluguName(teluguName);
            dataModel.setPlace(place);
            dataModel.setDueAmount(dueAmount);

            stringBuffer.append(dataModel);
            data.add(dataModel);
        }
        return data;
    }
}
```

to this table i need to insert this json data
    **APi** - http://demo4896782.mockable.io/shops

```
[
  {
    "shopName": "Hello World.",
    "shopTeluguName": "శరవాన గుడ్డు పంపిణీదారులు",
    "shopAddress": "Bomanahalli",
    "previousDues": 0,
    "shopID": 1
},
{
    "shopName": "Hello World.",
    "shopTeluguName": "శరవాన గుడ్డు పంపిణీదారులు",
    "shopAddress": "Bomanahalli",
    "previousDues": 20,
    "shopID": 2
},
{
    "shopName": "Hello World.",
    "shopTeluguName": "శరవాన గుడ్డు పంపిణీదారులు",
    "shopAddress": "Bomanahalli",
    "previousDues": 400,
    "shopID": 3
}
]
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: or you could just store the 'json-string' as a string in a table and serialize or deserialize using **Gson** library as needed by using a model class.

Comment: i couldn't do that, would please show example program.

Comment: you first need to create a model class suggested below you can easily create a model class in android studio using RoboPojo genererator for json to model class it easy to implement if your response is in the same format as it is coming. Its one of the most useful plugin in android studio.

Comment: need to know how to implement this go to this link https://github.com/robohorse/RoboPOJOGenerator

Answer (score 0):

The code below assumes you can parse the json data from the server.

```
public void insert(JsonObject jsonObject){
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    values.put("shopName", jsonObject.getString('Hello World'));
    values.put("shopTeluguName", jsonObject.getString('shopTeluguName'));
    values.put("shopAddress", jsonObject.getString('shopAddress'));
    values.put("previousDues", jsonObject.getString('previousDues'));
    values.put("shopID", jsonObject.getString('shopID'));

    db.insert("YOUR TABLE NAME", null, values);
}
```

Now simply iterate over the JSON Array and call this function in the loop

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the table structure should be:

`CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "TABLE_NAME" + "(" + JSON_STRING_KEY + " TEXT ")`

Now, make a model class for the json-array you're getting from api.

Now, to **insert** this json-array in the table, you can do something like this:

```
 void insertJsonArrayAsStringToTable(ArrayList<Model> modelList) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.delete(TABLE_NAME, null, null); // delete previous data
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
   // array list as a string; or you can directly put the string you got from 
   // onResponse(String response) of your volley StringRequest--if you're using it
    contentValues.put(JSON_STRING_KEY, new Gson().toJsonTree(modelList).toString());  
    db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);
    db.close();
}
```

Until now, we have the json-array data from the api stored in the table as a string.

Now, we can use a query to **retrieve the string from table** and again use Gson to **convert it into an object**( here, an `ArrayList` of `Model`):

```
 public ArrayList<Model> loadData() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor res = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME, null); // now where-clause, so we simply use null as an argument
    res.moveToFirst();
    ArrayList<Model> modelList= null;
    while (!res.isAfterLast()) { // traverse the table
        Type listType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<Model>>() {
        }.getType();
        modelList= new Gson().fromJson(res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(JSON_STRING_KEY)), listType);
        res.moveToNext();
    }
    res.close();
    db.close();
    return modelList;
}
```

PS: How you manage to store other possible responses coming from api into the db, totally depends on you, whether make separate tables or something like that.